# Modal works on computer, but floats to the top when on mobile device

Tags: html, css

So I created a modal with the following **CSS**:

```
<style>
    .modal-mask {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9998;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        display: table;
        transition: opacity .3s ease;
    }

    .modal-container {
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 20px 30px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
        transition: all .3s ease;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

</style>
```

And the following **HTML**:

```
<div class="modal-mask" id = "answerEditor">
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-4">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Answer editor to review
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        modal body right here
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                Footer
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above works fine when I view it on the computer, however whenever I go to mobile, the Modal floats all the way to the top instead of centering in the view of the user.

Any ideas of what could be going wrong?

I've tried tweaking a lot of the CSS and have gotten nowhere, and I can't check the CSS differences between the mobile version and the computer.

**EDIT** the above code uses bootstrap as well: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Could you post an image of the pc view and the phone view?

Comment: Forgot to add: it also uses bootstrap

Comment: @Derek Did my answer solve this issue for you?

Comment: @Zze unfortunately it did not, I had to find a way outside of using the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tweaked some of your html and css so it can effectively use the `transform: transate()` method of centring content.

Also, I am not sure what the `.modal-container` css currently applies to as this class is not in your html.

Just a note, `translate` is a css3 property, so you might want to ensure that you can use it on your target devices (you didn't specifically say). http://caniuse.com/#search=translate

```css
body{
  height: 5000px;
}
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
.modal-container {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.panel{
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="modal-mask" id="answerEditor">
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Answer editor to review
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        modal body right here
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            Footer
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

I have changed this to use `100vh` and `100vw` for the `.modal-mask`. I also set body to 5000px just for the benefit of having scrolling in the snippet now.

Comment: Thanks, but even in mobile view, if I'm scrolled down the page and click the button to display the modal, it shows up all the way at the top. It doesn't do that on the computer though, which is why its blowing my mind

Comment: @Derek what mobile are you on?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S7

Comment: @Derek Can you please check this new snippet. Also, I assume that you are clearing cache ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to produce a modal at the top regardless of mobile or pc:

Here is my recreation using your code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb8C0.jpg

Comment: That's not the issue mentioned.

Comment: I would have added it as a comment for clarity had I had enough reputation.